# .htaccess file issue while redirecting from index.php to normal link when on home page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

I am working on a **LARAVEL 5.3** application and trying to redirect all requests with `index.php` to without `index.php`
e.g.: if someone enters `example.com/index.php/some-uri-segments`,
it should redirect to `example.com/some-uri-segments`.
I have successfully achieved this with following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#index.php to normal
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

**But there is a problem when the link is `example.com/index.php`.**

The request with `example.com/index.php` is redirected to `example.com/var/www/html/public`
But I want it to be redirected to only `example.com`.

Comment: Shouldn't Laravel work without the `index.php` in the URI in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `/` in your code. Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you checked your local host settings ? do you have `AllowOverride` And also does it include `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` ?

Comment: I think you are talking about "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf" file.

Comment: [code]<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName www.example.com
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /root/example.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/example.com.key
 SSLCACertificateFile /root/intermediate.crt
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
 <Directory “/var/www/html/public”>
 AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
[/code]